# Why doesn't all profiles expand on hover?

Tags: support

Why doesn't the profile abstraction section expand on profile hover at any of the posts by [this user](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/18916/jojo)?

Contradictory, the profile abstraction section expands well on profile hover at any of the posts by [this user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/63550/peter-mortensen).

What is the difference?

Comment: because it's a [privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user), that's assuming your talking about the first user's Stack Overflow account which only has 157 rep (not 33,851 which is what they have on Arqade)

Comment: @Memor-X So, it's just a matter of 28+ characters in the "About Me" and 1k+ rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Expanded Usercard is one of the privileges you earn when you become an [Estabilished User](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) (i.e., get 1K rep, or 750 rep on beta sites). Additionally, it only applies to users who have at least 28 characters in their "About Me" section, regardless of rep.

Comment: so in short i can't see a profile on hover if that user doesn't have at least 28 characters in their "About Me" section ?